# Javascript add Listener error: TypeError: trigger.addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I'm adding listeners to one link or multiple links, using the following code:

```
 function getData() {
            var context = {};
            context['triggers'] = triggers();
            context['msg'] = msg;
            return context
        }

function triggers() {
            var arr = [];
            document.querySelectorAll('.trigger').forEach(function (trigger, index) {
                arr[index] = {};
                arr[index]['trigger'] = trigger;
            });
            return arr;
        }



function addListeners(data) {
            data.triggers.forEach(function (trigger) {
                trigger.addEventListener('click', change)
            });
        }

data = geData()
```

Trigger is an anchor:

[image]

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: trigger.addEventListener is not a function
```

Comment: Please post the code which calls `addListeners` with `data`, especially, what do you send in `data`.

Comment: This means one of two things: 1. `trigger` isn't an HTML element, or 2. You're doing this on an obsolete version of IE that doesn't support `addEventListener` (or are using IE9-IE11 in the broken "compatibility" mode).

Comment: @31piy  updated with more code

Comment: T.J Crowder; if I use trigger 'instanceof Element' I get false, but in Developer Tools appear as being an anchor

Comment: @user3541631 - You're misreading what devtools is showing you (easily done!). It's showing you an object with a `trigger` property whose value is the anchor element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object in `triggers` isn't the anchor, it's an object that contains the anchor as a property called `trigger`. So:

```
function addListeners(data) {
    data.triggers.forEach(function (entry) {            // *** `entry` instead of `trigger`
        entry.trigger.addEventListener('click', change)
// -----^^^^^^
    });
}
```

We know this because of this code:

```
function triggers() {
    var arr = [];
    document.querySelectorAll('.trigger').forEach(function (trigger, index) {
        arr[index] = {};
        arr[index]['trigger'] = trigger;
    });
    return arr;
}
```

That's clearly creating an object, then setting the element as a `trigger` property on it.

---

Side note: You can use property initializers and property literal syntax in several places where you're using strings, and FWIW you can apply `map` to a `NodeList`:

```
function getData() {
    return {
        triggers: triggers(),
        msg: msg
    };
}

function triggers() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(
        document.querySelectorAll('.trigger'),
        function(anchor) {
            return {trigger: anchor};
        }
    );
}

function addListeners(data) {
    data.triggers.forEach(function (entry) {
        entry.trigger.addEventListener('click', change)
    });
}

data = geData();
```